# MySQL Inner Join query only returning one result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables in my DB: `users` and `tickets`.  The `users` table has the users info and the `tickets` table has the tickets information with a `user_id` associated to the `users` table.  Easy enough.  The issue I'm running into is when I run an `INNER JOIN` MySQL query and `print_r` the results I'm getting one result when I should be getting multiple results as you can see from using the same MySQL query in SequelPro:  http://screencast.com/t/dwrVExxLPS

**CODE**

```
$sql = "SELECT tickets.user_id, ticket_text, username FROM tickets INNER JOIN users ON tickets.user_id = users.id";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

This is what is dumped out via the `print_r` function: http://screencast.com/t/c5Llsb8Mj7y

Why only one result?

Comment: `fetch` only returns one row from the database. Either use a loop to iterate through the resultset, or use `fetchAll` to get all the results at once

Comment: Ahh, rookie mistake!  My bad guys!  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, this line:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Should be changed to:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```